# Is it good practice to send a delayed semaphore_signal to a semaphore in a macOS Grand Central Dispatch App?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-blocks

I am using semaphores and GCD in a macOS Objective-C Application. I have this common scenario :

```
dispatch_semaphore_t fd_sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // Perform some activity
        // But can potentially never complete

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(fd_sema);
});

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(10 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(fd_sema);
});

dispatch_semaphore_wait(fd_sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Basically, here I am trying to obtain a timeout on a operation. Given that the argument of dispatch_semaphore_wait can only be now or forever, I am using the dispatch_after block to implement a timeout. Do you think this is good practice or it can lead to problems and crashes ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Might your activity really *never* complete? Then you might be permanently wasting a thread by putting it on a global dispatch queue. Since it might be slow, why are you currently doing it on the **main** queue? Seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where'd you get the idea that the timeout on `dispatch_semaphore_wait()` can only be now or forever? That's not correct. You can pass the result from `dispatch_time()` just like you're using with `dispatch_after()`. Therefore, there's no need to implement a timeout yourself.

Comment: That was under my eyes ! Probably it was late at night :), but I tried looking at the headers and I came across an opaque time structure that could only be set in a documented way to now or forever. For sure it was not exactly the time struct used here. Thanks a lot !